# Solve giving solution when there is no solution

Tags: equation-solving

I got a strange result from `Solve`.

I have the following relations:

```
eq = 
  {1/2 (-2 - c[31, 33]) == 0, 
   -c[31, 32] == 0, 
   1/2 (1 + 1/2 c[31, 33] - c[31, 32] c[32, 31] - 1/2 c[31, 32] c[32, 33]) != 0, 
   2/(1 + 1/2 c[31, 33] - c[31, 32] c[32, 31] - 1/2 c[31, 32] c[32, 33]) != 0};
```

I evaluated

```
sol = Solve[And @@ eq, {c[31,32],c[31,33]}]
```

and got

> `{{c[31, 32] -> 0, c[31, 33] -> -2}}`

The solution is wrong since the second to last relation is not fulfilled. The system has no solution.

`Reduce` does the job, but that's beside the point.

I am using Mathematica 12.0.0 Kernel for Linux x86 (64-bit)

Has someone encountered a similar behavior and/or recognizes whats going wrong?

Comment: same result on `10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)`.

Comment: There are more equations than the two unknowns for which you are solving. Use the option [`MaxExtraConditions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxExtraConditions.html) and `Solve` will indicate that there is no solution: `sol = Solve[eq, {c[31, 32], c[31, 33]},
  MaxExtraConditions -> All]`

Comment: Moreover, Solve[And @@ eq, {c[31, 32], c[31, 33]}, Method -> Reduce] performs the same result {{c[31,32]->0,c[31,33]->-2}} in version 12.0 on Windows 10 32 bit.

Comment: @BobHanlon Is the described behavior without  "MaxExtraConditions -> All" expected?

Comment: @Amin - "expected" by whom? What I would expect is to always verify solutions using `eq /. sol` and when the that verification raises questions, to look at Solve's (or other function's) options to see if they might help.

Comment: @BobHanlon Expected from the documentation. For me, it is does not become clear from the documentation that this can happen. That would mean:
1.)  unexpected wrong output == bug --> I should report it. 
2.) expected wrong output or known issue: I should not report it.

My question is basically: Should I report it officially?

Comment: From the documentation for `Solve | Options | MaxExtraConditions`, **"By default, Solve drops inequation conditions on continuous parameters"**. The way you posed the question, `c[32, 31]` and `c[32, 33]` are continuous parameters involved in inequations. After dropping those inequations, the returned solution satisfies the remaining two equations.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks! That was the part I did not appreciate. That clarifies matters. Do you want to write it as an answer or can I close the question right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eq = {
   1/2 (-2 - c[31, 33]) == 0,
   -c[31, 32] == 0,
   1/2 (1 + 1/2 c[31, 33] - c[31, 32] c[32, 31] - 1/2 c[31, 32] c[32, 33]) != 
    0,
   2/(1 + 1/2 c[31, 33] - c[31, 32] c[32, 31] - 1/2 c[31, 32] c[32, 33]) != 
    0};

sol = Solve[And @@ eq, {c[31, 32], c[31, 33]}]

(* {{c[31, 32] -> 0, c[31, 33] -> -2}} *)
```

However, the `sol` does not fully satisfy the system.

```
eq /. sol

(* Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.

{{True, True, False, True}} *)
```

From the documentation for `Solve | Options | MaxExtraConditions`, **"By default, Solve drops inequation conditions on continuous parameters"**. The way you posed the question, `c[32, 31]` and `c[32, 33]` are continuous parameters involved in inequations. After dropping those inequations, the returned solution satisfies the remaining two equations.

Use the option [`MaxExtraConditions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxExtraConditions.html) and `Solve` will indicate that there is no solution:

```
sol = Solve[eq, {c[31, 32], c[31, 33]}, MaxExtraConditions -> All]

(* {} *)
```